# Keeping sepration of concerns using entity framework 7 and asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hi I am starting a new project using asp.net 5.I know it is not production ready yet but what I am building will not be production ready until the end of the year so I will start with it.

I want to have a standard 3 layer architecture for the project.To that end I have created the following project structure:

[image]

Now from what I have seen online in order to register entity framework in the app I have to do the following in the Statup class of the client app:

```
   services.AddEntityFramework()
           .AddSqlServer()
           .AddDbContext<ProductDbContext>();
```

This basicly brakes the separation of concerns the client should not have any ideea what database type or data access technology the application is using.
I might be missing somethign since I just started looking into asp.net 5 and entity framework 3 days ago.

Is there any way to mantain the separation of concerns using entity framework 7 and asp.net 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create extension methods of IServiceCollection in the different layers of your app to avoid having all the references in the web app.

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterDbContext(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
           .AddSqlServer()
           .AddDbContext<ProductDbContext>();
    }
}
```

Then, in  Startup.cs:

```
using My.Service.Tier.ExtensionNamespace;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.RegisterDbContext();
}
```

now your web app only needs references to your service layer instead of a direct reference to data access stuff